# Finding $y$ coordinates for $\sin(x+y)=x^2+y^2$

Tags: equation-solving

How can I find the $y$ coordinates of the equation $\sin(x+y)=x^2+y^2$ when $x=0.5$? I've tried

```
 NSolve[Sin[x + y] = x^2 + y^2 /. x -> 0.5, y]
```

Comment: `FindRoot[Sin[x + y] == x^2 + y^2 /. x -> 1/2, {y, 1}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: The problem with your `NSolve` command is that you use `=`, which assigns values to variables, instead of `==`, which is the equality sign.  Then you have to set the domain of the solutions to the real numbers, as shown in my answer.

Comment: `Solve[]` can deal with it if you make the right restrictions: `Solve[{Sin[x + y] == x^2 + y^2, x == 1/2}, {x, y}, Reals]`.

Answer (score 10):

Let us first plot what we know

```
ContourPlot[{Sin[x + y] == x^2 + y^2, x == 0.5}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Means we have to find two solutions

```
sol = FindRoot[Sin[x + y] == x^2 + y^2 /. x -> 1/2, {y, {-1, 1}}]
```

and the y coordinates are:

> `{y -> {-0.204059, 0.852172}}`

And we can apply rules to this variable

```
myYpoint = y /. sol
```

> `{-0.204059, 0.852172}`

The same procedure for the variable x

```
myXpoint = {0.5, 0.5}
```

> `{0.5, 0.5}`

And a combination of both, giving us a nice List

```
IntrsctnPoints = Transpose[{myXpoint, myYpoint}]
```

> `{{0.5, -0.204059}, {0.5, 0.852172}}`

and we can plot

```
ContourPlot[{Sin[x + y] == x^2 + y^2, x == 0.5}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point /@ IntrsctnPoints}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very beautiful answer!

Answer (score 7):

As belisarius pointed out, this will find an answer

```
FindRoot[Sin[x + y] == x^2 + y^2 /. x -> 1/2, {y, 1}]
(* {y -> 0.852172} *)
```

But we can see graphically that there should be two answers

```
Show[Plot3D[{Sin[y + x], x^2 + y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> 25], 
 ContourPlot3D[x == 0.5, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  ContourStyle -> Purple]]
```

[image]

So you can manually get them by giving `FindRoot` two different starting points

```
FindRoot[
   Sin[x + y] == x^2 + y^2 /. x -> 1/2, {y, #}] & /@ {-1, 1}
(* {{y -> -0.204059}, {y -> 0.852172}} *)
```

But in this case, you can also use `NSolve` and it will find both answers

```
NSolve[Sin[x + y] == x^2 + y^2 /. x -> 0.5, y, Reals]
(* {{y -> -0.204059}, {y -> 0.852172}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a better workaround  than others I think.You can visualize it first:

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x+y],x^2+y^2},{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}]
```

[image]

Then get the `ImplicitRegion` of `Sin[x + y] == x^2 + y^2`,The result you want is appearing.

```
r1=ImplicitRegion[Sin[x+y]==x^2+y^2,{x,y}];
result=RegionMember[r1,{1/2,y}]//Reduce//N
```

> (*y==-0.204059||y==0.852172*)

Answer (score 2):

We give a parametric form of the curve of the equation

```
Sin[x+y] == x^2 + y^2;
```

Let

```
x = (a+b)/2; y = (a-b)/2;
```

Then we have

```
Sin[a] = 1/2 (a^2 + b^2)
```

hence

```
b = +- Sqrt[ 2 Sin[a] - a^2 ]
```

Which gives the parametric form of (half) the curve

```
{x[a],y[a]} -> { a + Sqrt[ 2 Sin[a] - a^2 ], a - Sqrt[ 2 Sin[a] - a^2 ] }
```

The full curve is obtained by putting two pieces together

```
ParametricPlot[{
  {1/2 (a + Sqrt[2 Sin[a] - a^2]), 1/2 (a - Sqrt[2 Sin[a] - a^2])}, 
  {1/2 (a - Sqrt[2 Sin[a] - a^2]), 1/2 (a + Sqrt[2 Sin[a] - a^2])}
                }, {a, 0, \[Pi]/2}]

(* Output not shown, see pictures in the answers by others here *)
```